# Create an Angular Pipe Filter with timestamp field

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I'm trying to create a filter pipe for my Angular 4 script. I need to filter a timestamp field of the array, but I did not found an example, here is my code :

First my array structure
[image]

I need to make the Pipe Filter using the indate: Date (field)

My Pipe Filter Code: I'm trying this, but its not working:

```
@Pipe({  
    name: 'myfilter',  
    //pure: false  
})  

export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {  
    transform(items: any[], searchText: any ): any[] {  
        if (!items || !searchText) {  
            return items;  
        }  
        return items.filter(item => item.indate(searchText.indate));

    }  
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to filter "indate" field, that is a timestamp field in my array, but it has two parts: date and time and I don not know how to  check only for the date part with the searchText variable.
Hope anybody understand and give me a tip.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Is `indate` a javascript `Date` object?

Comment: It's a timestamp object

Comment: @CaribeSoft try this.     items.map(item => {
    item.indate= item.indate.substr(item.indate.indexOf(' ')+1);
    item.indate = item.indate.split('T')[0];
  });

Comment: Hi Rahul, I'm receiving this error message : ERROR TypeError: "item.indate.indexOf is not a function"